# How to add numeric value as seconds to a datetime field and report data in new column

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2005

I need to convert the ElapsedTime field into hours/minutes/seconds and add that to the creationtime field and have the results reported into a new column that I'll call EndTime. Here is the query I have to gather the data:

```
select 
ElapsedTime, ChannelUsed, documents.creationtime 
from 
historytrx (nolock) inner join 
history on 
historytrx.handle = history.handle inner join 
documents on 
history.owner = documents.handle inner join 
DocFiles on 
documents.docfiledba = docfiles.handle 
where 
creationtime > '2015-02-02 20:00:00.000' and 
creationtime < '2015-02-02 20:01:00.000'  and 
RemoteServer = 'DMG4120-01668' and 
ElapsedTime != '0'
```

Here is the current output:

```
ElapsedTime   ChannelUsed    creationtime
1042          1              2015-02-02 20:00:03.000
27            35             2015-02-02 20:00:05.000
57            50             2015-02-02 20:00:05.000
```

Here is my desired output:

```
ElapsedTime   ChannelUsed    creationtime             EndTime
1042          1              2015-02-02 20:00:03.000  2015-02-02 20:17:39.000
27            35             2015-02-02 20:00:05.000  2015-02-02 20:00:32.000
57            50             2015-02-02 20:00:05.000  2015-02-02 20:01:03.000
```

Thanks to everyone in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Search DateAdd(), should give you what you want...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select 
 ElapsedTime, 
 ChannelUsed, 
 creationtime, 
 convert(datetime, dateadd(ss,elapsedtime,creationtime), 121) as endTime
from 
 historytrx t inner join 
 history h on 
 t.handle = h.handle inner join 
 documents d on 
 h.owner = d.handle inner join 
 DocFiles f on 
 d.docfiledba = f.handle 
where 
 creationtime > '2015-02-02 20:00:00.000' and 
 creationtime < '2015-02-02 20:01:00.000'  and 
 RemoteServer = 'DMG4120-01668' and 
 ElapsedTime != '0'
```

see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  select 
    ElapsedTime, ChannelUsed, documents.creationtime,
    dateAdd(ss,ElapsedTime,documents.creationtime) as EndTime
    from 
    historytrx (nolock) inner join 
    history on 
    historytrx.handle = history.handle inner join 
    documents on 
    history.owner = documents.handle inner join 
    DocFiles on 
    documents.docfiledba = docfiles.handle 
    where 
    creationtime > '2015-02-02 20:00:00.000' and 
    creationtime < '2015-02-02 20:01:00.000'  and 
    RemoteServer = 'DMG4120-01668' and 
    ElapsedTime != '0'
```

The DateAdd() function takes 3 parameters.  The ss stands for seconds, the second parameter is the number of seconds to add, and the third is the starting date to add the seconds value to.